# Header Image in Blogger not staying in center on browser window resize

Tags: css, background, header, center, blogger

My first question.  I've searched around on here for similar topics, but nothing is really quite what I am after.

I am designing my blog on Blogger, and everything is going pretty smoothly, but I've hit a minor (not too important) snag, that I wouldn't mind remedying.  I have my 'header-wrapper' background image centered on my page nicely, but I don't like the fact that when I make my browser window smaller, the background image (a.k.a my header) stays put; relative to the conent-wrapper I suppose.

What I want, is for my header to stay centered relative to the entire page.  This way, when I resize my window, my header will constantly be in the middle of the screen.

Here is the relevant css for my issue (or at least I think it is!)

```
body {

background: #fefefe;
background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/261790905/Background.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left top;
margin:0;
color: #757575;
font: verdana;
font-size: 11px;
text-align: center;

}

#header-wrapper {
background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/261790905/headerpngshort.png);
width: 500px;
height: 184px;
margin:0 auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My website for reference.  http://rebelchanel.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not 100% sure what you are after, but if you want to have the Content of your header in the middle of your page no matter what size it is, you can use this code:

```
#header-wrapper {
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 184px;
clear: both;
}
```

What this does, is that the wrapper is centered on the middel of the page with 250px on each side of the middle. this is the best way for me to explain it. If it's not what your looking for then I will find another code that can center things like image or divs in the middle.

Comment: Bugger.  It's still not working.  Thank-you though! Is there any other information you need?

Comment: I'm looking at your block, if you can specify exacly what the problem is, is it the logo in the header or?

Comment: No, the grey horizontal bar is the body background repeating x.  The 'rebelchanel' logo is in the header-wrapper, and it is a .png.  It is separate from the grey background image.

Comment: Just to be sure, is it the Text/img that says Rebel Chanel in the header you can to be centeret?